# Is there a hotkey for moving whole collections around?

Tags: collections

pretty basic question:

Does anyone know of an easy way to select a collection and use a hotkey to move it to it's desired location?

I have tried a lot of different ways involving (M, ctrl + M, ctrl + G) and I can't seem to figure it out.

I just don't want to always have to drag and drop collections around, I want a way to move them around as fast as I can move objects around.

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select all objects in your collection.
Then move them around as one object.

*Select > Select Grouped > Collection*
Shortcut: <kbd>Shift+G</kbd>

[image]

Comment: so is there no similar way to move collections like " M " does with object ?

That seems so strange.

Comment: Well, there are *collection instances*, which behave exactly like objects. I use them all the time :). (and the shortcut to move stuff is *G*)